# Uso de if con operador ternario

Tags: condiciones, operador, operador-ternario

a veces veo que escriben el if normal y otras el if con operador ternario. De que depende usar una u otra opcion? Muchas gracias

```
if(condicion){
}


(condicion)
   ?
   :
```

Comment: A veces simplemente es para reducir líneas de código y ponerlo todo en una misma línea cuando se trata de sentencias sencillas

Comment: Saludos. En el caso de `if` como puede crecer tanto como se necesite con `else if` y/o al final el `else`; el ternario ademas de simplificar en una sola línea la instrucción es cuando solo su **condicion** tiene como resultado 2 valores y solo uno tomara; es decir no sería "correcto" el `(condicion1) ? 'en caso true' : ((condicion2)? 'en caso true condicion 2':'en caso falso condicion 2')`; y así anidarlas.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador ternario se suele utilizar cuando haces una asignación en una sola línea mientras que el if normal se suele utilizar cuando se van a ejecutar varias acciones en caso de que dicho if sea verdadero.

Un ejemplo de if normal:

```
if (micondicion) {
    EjecutaAlgo();
    EjecutaAlgoMas();
}
```

Un ejemplo de if con operador ternario:

```
var miValor = (micondicion) ? "es verdad" : "es mentira";
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias